# Pandas groupby sequential values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have no idea how to call this operation, so I couldn't really google anything, but here's what I'm trying to do:

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B"], "value":[3, 1, 2, 0, 5, 2, 3]})
df
  name  value
0    A      3
1    B      1
2    B      2
3    B      0
4    A      5
5    A      2
6    B      3
```

And I want to group it on `df.name` and apply a `max` function on `df.values` but only if the names are in sequence. So my desired result is as follows:

```
df.groupby_sequence("name")["value"].agg(max)
  name  value
0    A      3
1    B      2
2    A      5
3    B      3
```

Any clue how to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `pandas`, you can groupby when the name changes from row to row, using `(df.name!=df.name.shift()).cumsum()`, which essentially groups together consecutive names:

```
>>> df.groupby((df.name!=df.name.shift()).cumsum()).max().reset_index(drop=True)
  name  value
0    A      3
1    B      2
2    A      5
3    B      3
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a pandas solution, but you could use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from itertools:

```
from operator import itemgetter

import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby

df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B"], "value":[3, 1, 2, 0, 5, 2, 3]})

result = [max(group, key=itemgetter(1)) for k, group in groupby(zip(df.name, df.value), key=itemgetter(0))]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[('A', 3), ('B', 2), ('A', 5), ('B', 3)]
```