# Pandas dataFrame using groupby but repeating non sequential values

Tags: python, pandas

I m new to pandas, and need the following :
my DataFrame looks like

```
'a'    'b'
S1      4
S1      7
S2      1
S2      3
S2      9
S1      4
```

I d like to group it by column a, but grouping only subsequent lines, so the result of calling count on the groupby would get me something like

```
S1   2
S2   3
S1   1
```

Is there an option or another function to achieve this ?
Thanks

Comment: This is a better dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53091343/pandas-groupby-sequential-values

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Even though I searched, I could not get to this one